# ASP.Net get information from dynamically created rows in a table

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

I have this table here that can add and remove rows. This works perfectly fine.

```
<asp:Table ID="SiteInfo" runat="server" Style="border-style: solid">
    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell Style="border-style: solid">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Name of Site">
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell Style="border-style: solid">
            <asp:Label runat="server" Text="Territory">
            </asp:Label>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>

    <asp:TableRow>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Site1" runat="server" Style="border-style: solid"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
        <asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TextBox ID="Territory1" runat="server" Style="border-style: solid"></asp:TextBox>
        </asp:TableCell>
    </asp:TableRow>
</asp:Table>
<br />
<asp:Button ID="addSite" runat="server" Text="Add a Site" OnClientClick="javascript:addRow();"></asp:Button>
<asp:Button ID="removeSite" runat="server" Text="Remove" OnClientClick="javascript:removeRow();"></asp:Button>
<!-- Add a row from the site table -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript">
    function addRow() {
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=SiteInfo.ClientID%>');
        var row = table.insertRow(table.rows.length);
        var cell1 = row.insertCell(0);
        var cell2 = row.insertCell(1);
        cell1.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="Site_' + table.rows.length + ' " Style="border-style: solid" />';
        cell2.innerHTML = '<input type="text" id="Territory_' + table.rows.length + ' " Style="border-style: solid" />';

    }
</script>
<!-- Remove a row from the site table -->
<script type="text/javascript" language="javascript" id="`">
    function removeRow() {
        var table = document.getElementById('<%=SiteInfo.ClientID%>');
        if (table.rows.length - 1 > 1)
            table.deleteRow(table.rows.length - 1);
    }
</script>
```

The problem is I have a submit button that needs to be able to read and send this information, but I don't know how to get the inputs from the new rows that were added to the table. Here is what I'm trying to do, but it doesn't work.

```
protected void submit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    if (Consent.Checked)
    {
        sb.Append("Site Name: " + Site1.Text + " | Territory : " + Territory1.Text + "\n");
        if (SiteInfo.Rows.Count > 2)
        {
            for (int i = 2; i < SiteInfo.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                sb.Append("Site Name: " + SiteInfo.Rows[i].Cells[0].Text + " Territory : " + SiteInfo.Rows[i].Cells[1].Text + "\n");
            }
        }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to understand this i advice you to understand asp.net [page life cycle](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.aspx).

***Background***
You are adding rows into your table on client side using JavaScript.New rows are created/deleted by browser (DOM maniuplation) when you invoke addRow()/removeRow() functions. Please note that this change takes place at client side.
When you click 'submit' button you 'postback' your webpage that is a request is sent by browser to the server and the page is loaded from scratch and after that your submit_Click function gets executed. At this point of time the changes you made on table on client side are NOT available and hence you DO NOT find newly created/deleted rows. You will only find what's been declared on aspx page.

***Solution***

Create a hidden field like :

```
<input type="hidden" id="tab_content" name="tab_content" />
```

On clientClick event of your 'submit' button call this function :

```
   function SaveTableData() {

                     var content = document.getElementById("tableClientID").innerHTML;

                     document.getElementById("tab_content").value = content;
                 };
```

Finally read this hidden fields value on submit_Click event.

The [Element.innerHTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML) property sets or gets the HTML syntax describing the element's descendants

```
// HTML:
// <div id="d"><p>Content</p>
// <p>Further Elaborated</p>
// </div>

const d = document.getElementById("d");
console.log(d.innerHTML);

// the string "<p>Content</p><p>Further Elaborated</p>"
// is dumped to the console window
```

Hope this helps !

Comment: What will                    
    " document.getElementById("tableClientID").innerHTML "                   
actually get?